# How to hide app bar button in different hub sections windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to C#. As I move on subsection the app bars stays the same only on the 3rd subsection that one button is hidden.

HubPage.xaml

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="mybar" ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal"  >
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Label="setting" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton x:Uid="CALENDAR" Label="calendar" Click="AppBarButton_Click">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <SymbolIcon x:Name="btnCalendar" Symbol="Calendar"/>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>

        </AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="btnLocation" x:Uid="MAP" Icon="MapPin" Label="location" Click="AppBarButton_Click"  />
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

HubPage.xaml.cs

```
private void Hub_SectionsInViewChanged(object sender, SectionsInViewChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {


                switch (MyHub.SectionsInView[0].Name)
                {
                    case "HubSection0":
                        btnCalendar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        btnLocation.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        break;
                    case "HubSection1":
                        btnCalendar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        btnLocation.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        break;

                    case "HubSection2":
                     btnCalendar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        btnLocation.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        break;
                    case "HubSection3":
                          btnCalendar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        btnLocation.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        break;
                    default:
                        return;
                }


            }
            finally
            {

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right your question, you set Name property not in the right place. You should set it for `AppBarButton` element, not for `SymbolIcon`. I think your code should work after this changes.

```
CommandBar x:Name="mybar" ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal"  >
    <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Label="setting" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
    </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    <AppBarButton x:Uid="CALENDAR" x:Name="btnCalendar" Label="calendar" Click="AppBarButton_Click">
        <AppBarButton.Icon>
            <SymbolIcon  Symbol="Calendar"/>
        </AppBarButton.Icon>
    </AppBarButton>
    <AppBarButton x:Name="btnLocation" x:Uid="MAP" Icon="MapPin" Label="location" Click="AppBarButton_Click"  />
</CommandBar>
```